# Pass resultset value as parameter in js function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp where i want to pass the resultset of a query as a parameter into a js function as a click event once button is clicked

Sample Code: (pop.jsp)

```
if("Site".equalsIgnoreCase(rset50.getString(1)))
  {
    rset70=stmt70.executeQuery("select site_id_pk from sd_development_sites where site_parent_fk='"+searchCondition+"' ");
    while (rset70.next())
    {  
     caseType1 = rset70.getString(1);  
    }
  %>
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Execute Test" onclick="show_site(caseType1);"/>

show_site=function (<value from resultset>)
{
  window.open(pop.jsp?CASEiD=<value from resultset>,options)
}
```

Could you please help me out in this? Please let me know if i missed any details.

Comment: Yes, you missed showing what show_site() does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `"show_site(caseType1);"` to `"show_site(<%= caseType1%>);"`

this will give you last selected ID from your recordset

if you want to pass whole recordset - you need to store it as array, then convert into js array notation and insert in the place above

Comment: @llya Bursov : thanks alot. Also i want to ask my click event is also not working.Is onclick="show_site(caseType1); is the cause for that.

Comment: @coolmego yes, as it suppose the caseType1 is javascript variable

Comment: open browser's developer tools and check what is in error console

Comment: @llya Bursov Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @llya Bursov I am getting the value for caseType. Thanks for that.

Comment: so, look into produced html code - maybe it is something wrong with JS declaration, for example you need `<script>function show_site(id) {window.open('pop.jsp?CASEiD='+id);}</script>`